# jQuery: Gmail Star?

Tags: jquery

I was wondering if anyone had any good tutorials around creating a gmail inbox star (favorite) ?

EDIT:

I guess I want to create something just like the stackoverflow star or gmail inbox star. I have a set of list items that i've added several controls to. One being a checkbox (for archiving, or batch deleting) and another I have a placeholder checkbox for favoriting. I'm just curious as to what the best approach is for making it snazzy with jquery.

Comment: You mean just an image that toggles on a click executing some Ajax call?

Comment: Can you explain your question further?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div id="[item id, probably a number]">
    <p><a href="javascript:" class="star">Favorite Me!</a></p>
</div>
```

CSS (use an image sprite for star):

```
.star {
     text-indent: -5000px;
     display: block;
     background: transparent url(../images/star.png) [coords for empty star];
     height: [height of star];
     width: [width of star];
}

.star.favorited {
     background-position: [coordinates for favorited star];
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() { 
    $('star').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).parents('div').attr('id');
        $(this).toggleClass('favorited');
        $.post('/yourUpdateUrl', 
               {'favorited': $(this).hasClass('favorited'), 'id': id},
                  function(data) { 
                     //some sort of update function here
                  });
         });
     });
});
```

Process on your backend how you will. Probably return how many favorites there are to update the page. Easy.

Comment: @EmmaMcCreary this is where your callback goes. whatever you need to do after you receive your response from the server. maybe update the number of favorites, give the user a message saying the favorite has been recorded, an error, whatever.

Comment: The durable backend is all the point. Client side: [using JSON in localStorage, on page load get value => .toggleClass() accordingly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776575/html5-localstorage-big-json-specific-value-as-condition-to-change-css-favorit/14776578#14776578) ; onclick .toggleClass() and update JSON.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you want less of a "rating" system (as mentioned in the other answers) and more of a "add this to favorites" system?

Something like this should get you started in the right direction. Others, feel free to chime in with other best-practices if you have them.

### foo.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.make_favorite.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.favorite').make_favorite();
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <a href="#article-15" class="favorite">
      <img src="star.gif" alt="Make it a favorite!" />
    </a>
    <a href="#image-12" class="favorite">
      <img src="star.gif" alt="Make it a favorite!" />
    </a>

  </body>
</html>
```

### jquery.make_favorite.js

```
(function($){
  $.fn.make_favorite = function(){

    var callback = function(response){
      console.log(response);
    };

    return this.each(function(){

      $(this).click(function(){
        var params = {
          item_type:  $(this).attr('href').match(/\w+/)[0],  // 'article'
          item_id:    $(this).attr('href').match(/\d+/)[0]   // 15
        };

        $.post('/favorite.php', params, callback, 'json');

        // stop event propagation
        return false;
      });
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

### favorite.php

```
<?php

// make_favorite function
function make_favorite($item_type, $item_id){
  return mysql_query(
    sprintf("insert into favorites (user_id, item_type, item_id) values (%d, '%s', %d);", $_SESSION['user_id'], $item_type, $item_id)
  );
}

// set header
header('Content-type: application/json');

// ensure to cleanse these inputs
$item_type = $_POST['item_type'];
$item_id = $_POST['item_id'];

if(make_favorite($item_type, $item_id)){
  $response = array('ok' => true, 'message' => 'Huzza!');
}
else {
  $response = array('ok' => false, 'message' => mysql_error());
}

// the magic?
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Comment: Nice but there's no code for displaying the shiny star on favorite items.

Comment: @Alexandre Jasmin, I did overlook that. Shouldn't be too tough to add in though :)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.codecapers.com/post/Building-a-Star-Rating-System-with-ASPNET-MVC-and-jQuery.aspx) is an article explaining how to build a star rating system with jquery and ASP.Net MVC.  It may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much you want two different images of a star.  One image is the plain white star and the other is the yellow (or whatever color) star that indicates it has been favorited.  On the click event of the image, you just check which image is the src and then change it accordingly to match the necessary status of favorited or not.  Then you run an ajax call to actually save the status to the database.

- The closest tutorial I found so far: http://www.9lessons.info/2009/09/favourite-rating-with-jquery-and-ajax.html

Answer (score 0):

I made it using jquery and [font-awesome](http://fontawesome.io/icons/), Will make an angular control and post it.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spotlmnop/Jpq7C/1/)

```
<label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked /><i class="icon-fixed-width icon-star"></i> One
   </label>
```