# Using AJAX to create a Gmail style star favourite icon

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm trying to recreate the Gmail 'star' favourite button using AJAX. Unfortunately what I have isn't working and I can't work out why.

I have the following in my HMTL:

```
<img id="item_1" src="/_images/star_off.gif" onclick="updateStar(this.id)" />
<img id="item_2" src="/_images/star_off.gif" onclick="updateStar(this.id)" />
```

And I'm using the following Javascript in a seperate file:

```
function updateStar(id) {
    var imgsrc = (document.getElementById(id).src == "/_images/star_off.gif") ? "/_images/star_on.gif" : "/_images/star_off.gif";
    var sendId = id.split('_')[1];
    var sendStar = (imgsrc == "/_images/star_off.gif") ? false : true;
    var objXml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var datasource = "favourite.php";
    var params = "id=" + sendId + "&star=" + sendStar;
    objXml.open("GET", datasource + "?" + params, true);
    objXml.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if ((objXml.readyState==4) && (objXml.status==200)) {
            alert('status changed.');
        }
    }
    objXml.send(null);
}
```

The script favourite.php sets inserts the id into a favourites database table (or removes it if star == false).

I can't see what is wrong here but it isn't working. I've also tried the suggestions on [jQuery: Gmail Star?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563094/jquery-gmail-star) but they wont work either. Any suggestions?

Comment: There's rarely a good reason to roll your own Ajax communication.  Is this just for personal learning?  Why not link to jQuery?

Comment: Since I don't need jQuery for anything else I wanted to try and keep it as lightweight as possible. I'm now thinking I'll need to, although still curious whether anyone can see why this solution shouldn't work.

Comment: @Jonathon: Though ‘use jQuery’ is not a bad comment, it isn't helpful in this situation, as there are flaws in his code.

Comment: @Paul: Did you try using breakpoints (e.g., in Firebug) to pinpoint the problem? And what browsers did you use to test this?

Comment: @Marcel Korpel The flaws are kind of the point.  Unless you're doing it for "fun", why would you recreate the wheel, or in this case, a wheel of torture?  This is a solved problem unless you're doing it for education.  I'd rather spend my time on the fun stuff (getting a feature to work) than kludgy DOM/browser quirks.

Comment: @Jonathon: No, the flaws *are* in his own code; see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Though it's hard to see where the problem is if you don't tell exactly *what* it is that's not working (e.g., the XMLHttpRequest call is never made, the final readyState or status are not reached), I see some flaws in your code. E.g., look at

```
var imgsrc = (document.getElementById(id).src == "/_images/star_off.gif") ? "/_images/star_on.gif" : "/_images/star_off.gif";
```

Here you're testing what the current status of the star is depending on the `src` property of the image. A quick test revealed that in Firefox 3.6.8 the `src` property contains the full URL of the image source, *including* protocol, domain and full path. So, in my test, the condition

```
(document.getElementById(id).src == "/_images/star_off.gif")
```

will always evaluate to `false`, always setting `imgsrc` to `"/_images/star_off.gif"` (so this function will never turn on the star).

A few lines later, you're testing the exact same condition again:

```
var sendStar = (imgsrc == "/_images/star_off.gif") ? false : true;
```

Try to avoid this kind of redundancy (e.g., using a boolean from the beginning); that will probably lessen the chance of introducing bugs. Moreover, in this case, the conditional operator (`? :`) is not necessary at all; this line could be rewritten to

```
var sendStar = (imgsrc != "/_images/star_off.gif");
```

but, as I said, try to avoid these kind of string comparisons to check the state of those stars.

IMHO, it's neater to either use two separate functions that turn on and off your star, so there's no need to test this at all, or send the state using a parameter, e.g.

```
<img id="item_1" src="/_images/star_off.gif" onclick="updateStar(this.id, true)" />
```

where `true` will turn on the star.

And of course it's neater to bind an event within your JavaScript (or even only show the star using JavaScript, so it's not shown when JS is unavailable).

Answer (score 0):

I'd check to see if the Xml Http Request is even firing, and if so, what value does it hold when it does. If you have the Safari browser, you can use the Web Inspector to see this. Under Web Inspector, go to Resources/XHR, and click on the url path that corresponds to the path you set in your ajax call. Then click on the Content tab and look at the output there. If it's blank, then you know the ajax call is failing. If it has a value, make sure it's the value you expect.

Comment: Most modern browser has some debug tool available. For Opera there is Menu > Page > Developer Tools > Opera Dragon Fly. For Firefox you can download Firebug. Even IE has its Tools > Developer Tools. The latter has no network profiler though, but if you download Fiddler Web Debugger, you should be able you to inspect all of your HTTP traffic.